# how to use ApplicationServices of IApplicationBuilder

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have asp.net core 3.1 web api app where I have registered a service as singleton,

```
services.AddSingleton<ISecretKeyReader, AzureKeyVaultReader>();
```

Now I am using `BuildServiceProvider` to register Logging like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddSingleton<ISecretKeyReader, AzureKeyVaultReader>();

        services.AddLogging((builder) =>
        {
            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ISecretKeyReader>();
        });
    }
```

This above code giving warning like,

> Calling `BuildServiceProvider` from application code result in an additional copy of singleton service being created. Consider alternative such as dependency injection as parameter to configure.

Now I am seeing we have `IServiceProvider` option in `IApplicationBuilder`,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var x = app.ApplicationServices;
}
```

But not sure how to use this in `ConfigureServices`. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help solve your problem, but one,

What if you use Transient instead if Singleton ...

services.AddTransient<ISecretKeyReader, AzureKeyVaultReader>();

Or, two ..

Pass IApplicationBuilder as an argument to the ConfigureServices method, so you a third parameter to that method that will be resolved using dependency injection.

Comment: can I pass 'IApplicationBuilder' as a argument to `ConfigureServices `   `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IApplicationBuilder app)`

Comment: Yes, but to keep the code simple, you can create a property and resolve the dependency in the constructor, private readonly IApplicationBuilder _app; initialize that in the constructor and use it in your ConfigureServices method

Comment: like this?    `private readonly IApplicationBuilder _app;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _app = app;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging((builder) =>
            {
                var secretReader = _app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ISecretKeyReader>();
                
            });`